# Add a "Reset App" button to my app? How to delete all files and directories in my data/data/app directory?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

I want to remove any application files/data/databases/shared preferences created in my application by adding a reset button in my app (Similar to spotify).

I thought at first that Context.fileList() would give me all of the files and directories in my directory and I should be able to erase them by iterating through them and calling Context.deleteFile().

Is there any way to effectively reset the applications internal/private data directory?